# JQuery - Multiple divs open/close independently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has multiple divs which I would like to open and close independently of each other. My code so far is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Einulfr/q4ra0gbb/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $("#show").show();
        $(".expandedText").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function () {
        $("#show").hide();
        $(".expandedText").show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Title of First Article</h2>

<p>Story introduction paragraph here...</p>
<a href="#" id="show">Read More...</a>

<div class="expandedText" style="display: none;>
    <p>Story continued here in second paragraph...</p>
    <p>Story continued here in third paragraph...</p> <a href="#" id="hide">Close Article</a>

</div>

<h2>Title of Second Article</h2>

<p>Story introduction paragraph here...</p>
<a href="#" id="show">Read More...</a>

<div class="expandedText" style="display: none;>
    <p>Story continued here in second paragraph...</p>
    <p>Story continued here in third paragraph...</p> <a href="#" id="hide">Close Article</a>

</div>
```

But as you can see, while the first one works fine, the subsequent divs do not, and also open and close with the first div's operations.
I also want the 'Read More...' to disappear when I click it, and return when I click 'Close Article'... This currently works, but all other solutions to similar questions seem to simply expand beneath the initial (Read More...) link, and requires the original link to be re-clicked to hide it again. I hope this makes sense :/

I am a complete novice when it comes to this kind of thing; what am I missing/doing wrong?

Great Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just like what @epascarello mentioned, an element id should be unique for the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change, all through :

- `id="show"` to `class="show"`
- `id="hide"` to `class="hide"`

Then :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hide").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".expandedText").hide().prev(".show").show();
    });
    $(".show").click(function () {
        $(this).hide().next(".expandedText").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is even better! Does everything I need it to. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

check code on the following url.

http://jsfiddle.net/q4ra0gbb/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".story .btnShow").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".expandedText").show();    
    });
    $(".story .btnHid").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();    
    });
});
```

I've created parent structure for each store and replaced some ids with classes.

Comment: Excellent, that helps heaps! Thank you so much!
Just one thing, is there a way to remove the 'Read More...' when its clicked, and restore it again when the corresponding 'Close Article' is clicked?

Comment: You're most welcome.. here's the updated link [http://jsfiddle.net/q4ra0gbb/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/q4ra0gbb/4/). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new, I restructured the code to be very basic and explained each section.  As others have stated, it is best practice to use `classes` for elements that are repeated on a page as `id` is meant for a single occurrence.

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function hideExpanded()
    {
        // Hide all expandedText divs that may be open
        $('div.expandedText').hide();

        // Show all the read more buttons
        $('a.show').show();
    }

    $('a.hide').click(function(e) {

        // Prevent the page from bouncing to the top
        e.preventDefault();

        // Close all of the expanded text and show the read more button
        hideExpanded();

    });
    $('a.show').click(function(e) {

        // Prevent the page from bouncing to the top
        e.preventDefault();

        // Close all of the expanded text and show the read more button
        hideExpanded();

        /*
         * Show the expandedText div associated with 
         * the parent element of the button clicked
         */
        $(this).parent().find('div.expandedText').show();

        // Hide the read more button that was just clicked
        $(this).hide();

    });
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="article">
    <h2>Title of First Article</h2>
    <p>Story introduction paragraph here...</p>
    <a href="#" class="show">Read More...</a>
    <div class="expandedText" style="display: none;">
        <p>Story continued here in second paragraph...</p>
        <p>Story continued here in third paragraph...</p>
        <a href="#" class="hide">Close Article</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <h2>Title of Second Article</h2>
    <p>Story introduction paragraph here...</p>
    <a href="#" class="show">Read More...</a>
    <div class="expandedText" style="display: none;">
        <p>Story continued here in second paragraph...</p>
        <p>Story continued here in third paragraph...</p>
        <a href="#" class="hide">Close Article</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a longer, drawn out answer to help you understand conceptually what should be happening and how it could work.  Once you understand the idea behind the code, you can shorten it.